# Rule 144a and Publicly Traded Companies

Tags: united-states, stocks, regulation, sec

Suppose you exercise an employee stock option and receive 100 Class A shares. Class A shares are publicly traded on the NASDAQ. Do you have to follow Rule 144?

Comment: Rule 144a is for "private placements". Seems like if the shares you received are publicly traded then they're not private placements. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thats what I thought but the regs aren't clear considering the options were given before the company was publicly traded.

Comment: @DStanley they have the 144a notice on them